# Bootcamp partition migration

Tags: mac, bootcamp, windows, vmware

On my old Macbook pro I had a Windows 7 64bit Bootcamp partition. When I got my new Macbook pro I transferred the Bootcamp partition to the new computer with Winclone. Now when I try to boot into Windows 7 it immediately goes to the BSOD. I can however boot into that partition just fine using VMWare Fusion.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this? My only guess is that it's either a driver issue or perhaps has something to do with the fact that I got the new Mac with a SSD.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with the SSD, but rather the drivers.  Your new MBP has a completely different chipset and CPU, which prevents Win 7 from loading.  When installing Win 7, it makes a specific install for your specific hardware.  When you are dealing with a different chipset/CPU, those "drivers" if you will are so low-level that they cannot be updated/modified.

You can try booting into safe mode.  When your computer starts to boot into Win 7, hit F8 repeatedly.  If the Windows boot logo comes up, you have waited too long.  When you get to the menu, select Boot into Safe Mode from the list.  It might allow you to boot into Windows, but I'm guessing you will still get a blue screen.

If that is the case, the only way to fix it is to do a fresh install of Win 7.  Although you can try to boot from the Win 7 DVD and try a repair, in my experience, this will not work.

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt you will be able to boot Windows 7 on the new machine in Boot Camp without doing some massive, massive troubleshooting and driver changes. I've tried many a time to do the same thing - move a Boot Camp partition to new machine and 100% it goes horribly. Windows makes its install specific to your hardware, unlike an OS X install, which can detect what hardware it's running on when you boot.

By far your best, easiest and fastest course of action is to reinstall Windows onto the new machine. Make sure you have your Windows product key handy, it's quite likely you may need to call Microsoft to get them to change the activation to the new machine (darned DRM schemes).

You can boot into VMWare because VMWare uses its own specific drivers, fired from the custom BIOS and other virtualization tricks it uses.

Answer (score 0):

The BSOD <strike>should</strike> might give you, or one of the readers of your question, an idea of what is going wrong.

Before you proceed further, you absolutely need to create a full backup of both the Mac and the Windows partitions.

Since it is Windows 7 it might then be worth a try to boot from the Windows 7 DVD and see if it can repair it.

Comment: All the BSOD suggested was to remove any hard drives I recently added.  I did try booting from the Windows 7 DVD, but it couldn't find any problems to repair.